# Cannot set property in javascript form

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined

I am getting the same error when trying to set other variables, `target` and `search`.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  I'm intending setting variables which I can pass to a backend `php` script which will then submit a request in order to sort search results. This should be simple but I'm not sure what the problem is.

How do I set these variables so that I can submit the form?

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="sort">
    <form name="loop54" action="cart.php" target="_self" method="get">
    <select id="sortBy">
        <option value="Rel" selected="selected">Relevance</option>
        <option value="PriceLoHi">Low to High</option>
        <option value="PriceHiLo">High to Low</option>
        <option value="A-Z">A-Z</option>
        <option value="Z-A">Z-A</option>
    </select>
    </form> 
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var selectmenu = document.getElementById("sortBy");
selectmenu.onchange=function() {
    var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    document.loop54.target="_self";
    document.loop54.sort = selectedOption;

    // the line below refers to another form and works
    document.loop54.search = document.ds_search.search.value;
    document.loop54.submit();
}
```

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y76rnfsn/) and it works there.  Must be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do ? Also what `ds_search` that you assume is inside `document` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `name` attribute for the `<select id="sortBy">` element:

```
<select id="sortBy" name="sort">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to your PHP script using an HTML form, you should not  manipulate the JavaScript object representing your HTML form.

The behaviour of your HTML form is this : if it contains fields with a name parameter (input tags with values, select tag with options selected), they will be sent in the HTTP Request, in an array where :

- the name of the field is the entry
- the value of the field is the value

So instead of doing what you do, you should :

- add a input text field named "search" where your user will type his search query
- add a name parameter to your select

Here's what it would look like :

```js
var selectmenu = document.getElementById("sortBy");
selectmenu.onchange= function() {
    // you can keep using JavaScript to submit your form, but select your form with its id : 
    document.getElementById("loop54").submit();
}
```

```html
 <div class="sort">
     <form id="loop54" pname="loop54" action="cart.php" target="_self" method="get">
     <select id="sortBy" name="sortBy">
      <option value="Rel" selected="selected">Relevance</option>
      <option value="PriceLoHi">Low to High</option>
      <option value="PriceHiLo">High to Low</option>
      <option value="A-Z">A-Z</option>
      <option value="Z-A">Z-A</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="search_ds"></input>
     </form>
    </div>
```

That way, you should end-up, server-side, with a $_GET variable containing an key/value for each of your fields : sortBy and search.